# Tracking & Updating Value Changes w/ Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am undertaking my largest Excel project yet, so I am looking for architecture advice from Excel gurus on how to accomplish this.

**Diagnosis:**

I have a large Excel spreadsheet hosted on SharePoint that is used to track employee skill qualification levels.  The spreadsheet is structured in a grid with employee names along the left side, specific job tasks along the top, and the intersections of these two contains a number corresponding to a skill level (and conditional formatting renders these integers as colored dots).

Green = high skilled

Yellow = low skilled

Blue = has not worked task in past 5 months

Red = has not worked task in past 6 months

If the skill is green or yellow and it has been 5 or more months with no assignment of a particular job task, then the skill rating should drop to blue or red.  If it’s already blue or red and a day comes up in which they do work that job task, then the skill rating should return to the color it was previously.  Additionally, some job tasks have cross-qualification with other tasks (e.g. any activity with task A will also count as activity for task B and C, and the employee’s skill level is the same for all of them).  An external spreadsheet contains employee attendance and assignment data (already generated by ADP).

**Goal:**

Currently, this skill rating is completely manually updated.  The goal is to **automate** the change of skill level (except for changes between high and low skill, these must still be manual) using a macro andor Excel cell functions.

**Prognosis:**

I know I can use VBA or VLOOKUP for the five/six-month logic test which determines a change to blue or red skill status. How would you Excel pros recommend I go about storing the green or yellow status and returning to that value when there is activity for that job task or any of its cross-qualifying tasks?  When it comes time to manually change a skilled status (switching between green and yellow) in the spreadsheet, how would I get the spreadsheet to update that change for all cross-qualifying tasks?

Comment: Firstly, you're aware that macros don't work in sharepoint so you need to download the document to update it with a macro?  Secondly, yes, what you want to do is possible.  If you have a sheet with each employee and the date they last worked each task type then you merely need to create a loop to update their colored circles based on that date sheet.  Run the macro and then upload it back to sharepoint.

Comment: The "display" can be formula-based, derived from the employee-skill assignments and last-worked dates stored elsewhere in the workbook.  You should not need to "store" the skill level in a separate location if the employee hasn't worked a particular task recently.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to provide you with code, when i dont know how the tables are set up.

There are a few ways to store the yellow or green skill level. I would make a colum that is before or after the data of the employees and just hide  it. You could make the interior of that cell the color of the skill level and update the cell with your macro. So then you could even change the color in the future. The red or blue status wouldnt be saved in these cell (if you wish so, you could take like 0 and 1 for that status). The macro would just check the last tasks of each employee and update everything.

If you need any more help, i would need to see schema of your workbook.